# How do I smoothen a copypasted then X axis inverted mesh and joined mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, mirror

I want to create an armature for my body and to be able to move its limbs asymmetrically, but to do so I realized the only thing I could do was to delete the mirror tool I had precedently used to make the mesh symmetrical, and then copypaste the mesh myself. I joined it to the original mesh to recreate a full body, but the juncture line is very sharp and I would like to make it smoother, as the human body is, to try and transform it into an as realistic body as possible. The problem is, when I go in sculpture mode, the two supposedly joined body halves are of a different color, and when trying to sculpt with a tool in one half it does the exact opposite effect it did in the other half. This may seem difficult to understand, so you will also find a couple of images that demonstrate what I am talking about. Another very annoying thing that happens is that when using any brush in the juncture line, the two body halves clip into each other making ridicolous curves and angles which result in an impossibility at making progress with the mesh. Thanks in advance for your help[image]

[image: what happens when using a brush on each half of the mesh]

[image: To show the mesh is only one]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an armature til you finish the mesh. So finish your character in t-pose first, texture it, make it some clothes, and only then move to rigging part. There is also a symmetry tool available on the n-panel in sculpting mode. But what I suggest you is to buy one good course about character creation for beginners. Don't pray for short youtube tutorials, cause the courses will give you a straight and clear pipeline and an understanding of the process itself. Right now your question doesn't have much sense cause you don't understand the basics. Just don't rush yourself. Start from scratch, repeat some tutorials one-to-one. And you'll get the answer pretty soon. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately, I have a null budget right now since I am a high school student living with my parents' salaries, hence I have to learn by myself or by using those youtube tutorials you pointed out. My question made simple is "how should I keep my mesh smooth without the mirror tool?"